# Find the value of an entire function

Tags: complex-analysis

If $g$ is an entire function with $g(3^{-n})=3^{-(n+1)}$ for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Find the value of $g(z)$ for every $z\in \mathbb{C}$.

My first thought is that $g(z)=\frac{z}{3}$, but I have no idea how to prove this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Your first thought is correct. Do you know any results about entire functions that are equal to each other on a set with a limit point?

Comment: I've tried assuming that there is a point $z$ such that $g(z) \neq \frac{z}{3}$, which means there exists a positive $r$ such that $\frac{z}{3}\notin B(g(z), r)$. Don't know if this is the correct approach, and I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: @clayton I don't think so no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

- $g$ is entire.
- zero is an accumulation point of the zeroes of $f(z)=g(z)-\frac{z}{3}$

What can you say about $f(z)$?